# SQL71501 :: Foreign Key: [dbo].[FK_AddressBook_Country] has an unresolved reference to Column [dbo].[AddressBook].[CountryID]

Tags: sql, asp.net-mvc, database, web, localdb

hope someone can help me. I have an error 
" SQL71501 :: Foreign Key: [dbo].[FK_AddressBook_Country] has an unresolved reference to Column [dbo].[AddressBook].[CountryID]. "
It red line the ([CountryID)]. I can't find where its fault. I actually followed this site http://demo.dotnetawesome.com/mvc/mycontactbook/part2 , I just changed the tables. Hopefully, someone can help me with this. Thank you so much!

```
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[AddressBook] (
    [Id]           INT           NOT NULL,
    [Name]         VARCHAR (50)  NOT NULL,
    [Surname]      VARCHAR (50)  NOT NULL,
    [Address1]     VARCHAR (200) NOT NULL,
    [Address2]     VARCHAR (100) NULL,
    [Postcode]     VARCHAR (6)   NOT NULL,
    [Town]         VARCHAR (20)  NOT NULL,
    [Country]      VARCHAR (50)  NOT NULL,
    [Email]        VARCHAR (50)  NOT NULL,
    [MobileNumber] VARCHAR (20)  NOT NULL,
    [PictureUser]  VARCHAR (200) NULL,
    PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED ([Id] ASC), 
    CONSTRAINT [FK_AddressBook_Country] FOREIGN KEY ([CountryID]) REFERENCES [Country]([CountryID])
);
```

```
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[Country] (
    [CountryID]   INT IDENTITY (1, 1) NOT NULL,
    [CountryName] VARCHAR (100) NOT NULL,
    PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED ([CountryID] ASC)
);
```

Comment: You don't have `CountryID` in `AddressBook`. You have `Country`. And it's of the wrong data type to be a FK reference to the `CountryID` in `Country`.

Comment: @Damien_The_Unbeliever oh gosh, thank you! didn't see that. Thank you so much!!

Answer (score 0):

this should work fine how ever there are two mistakes first in "FOREIGN KEY ([CountryID])" you have no field in the AdresseBook named "CountryId" i think you wanted the field "Country" as a foreign key if this is the case the  the Country field in adressBook must have the same type with CountryID of the table Country

```
 CREATE TABLE [dbo].[AddressBook] (
        [Id]           INT           NOT NULL,
        [Name]         VARCHAR (50)  NOT NULL,
        [Surname]      VARCHAR (50)  NOT NULL,
        [Address1]     VARCHAR (200) NOT NULL,
        [Address2]     VARCHAR (100) NULL,
        [Postcode]     VARCHAR (6)   NOT NULL,
        [Town]         VARCHAR (20)  NOT NULL,
        [Country]      INT  NOT NULL,
        [Email]        VARCHAR (50)  NOT NULL,
        [MobileNumber] VARCHAR (20)  NOT NULL,
        [PictureUser]  VARCHAR (200) NULL,
        PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED ([Id] ASC), 
        CONSTRAINT [FK_AddressBook_Country] FOREIGN KEY ([Country]) REFERENCES [Country]([CountryID])
    );
    CREATE TABLE [dbo].[Country] (
        [CountryID]   INT IDENTITY (1, 1) NOT NULL,
        [CountryName] VARCHAR (100) NOT NULL,
        PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED ([CountryID] ASC)
    );
```

Answer (score 0):

The same error happened to me because I added a space after the country and did not write it in SQL

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. Once you have sufficient [reputation](https://stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation) you will be able to [comment on any post](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/comment); instead, [provide answers that don't require clarification from the asker](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/214173/why-do-i-need-50-reputation-to-comment-what-can-i-do-instead). - [From Review](/review/late-answers/35306089)